# DBD/DBI: Crashes if a program is forked

Tags: perl, database

The below program works if the $crash parameter is not set:

```
$ perl example mysql://:tange@/tange/mytable
dburl mysql://:tange@/tange/mytable
databasedriver mysql user  password tange host  port  database tange table mytable query 
run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
run CREATE TABLE mytable
                (Seq INT,
                 Exitval INT
                 );
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
```

If $crash is set, bzip2 is run through open3, data sent via a forked process and this crashes DBD/DBI:

```
$ perl example mysql://:tange@/tange/mytable 1
dburl mysql://:tange@/tange/mytable
databasedriver mysql user  password tange host  port  database tange table mytable query 
run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
run CREATE TABLE mytable
                (Seq INT,
                 Exitval INT
                 );
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
Orig:
As bzip2:BZh9rE8P�
1
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at example line 157.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at example line 157.
```

This is also true, if using Postgresql:

```
$ perl example pg:////mytable 
dburl pg:////mytable
databasedriver pg user  password  host  port  database  table mytable query 
run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
run CREATE TABLE mytable
                (Seq INT,
                 Exitval INT
                 );
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
```

And with $crash set:

```
$ perl example pg:////mytable 1
dburl pg:////mytable
databasedriver pg user  password  host  port  database  table mytable query 
run DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
run CREATE TABLE mytable
                (Seq INT,
                 Exitval INT
                 );
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
Orig:
As bzip2:BZh9rE8P�
1
run INSERT INTO mytable (Seq,Exitval) VALUES (?,?);
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request. at example line 157.
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request. at example line 157.
```

Why? Is there a workaround?

To me open3 and fork are completely unrelated to DBD/DBI.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IPC::Open3;

my $sql = SQL->new(shift);
my $crash = shift;
$Global::debug = "all";
$sql->create_table();
$sql->insert_records(2);
$crash and print length string_zip("abc"),"\n";
$sql->insert_records(3);

sub string_zip {
    # Pipe string through 'cmd'
    my $cmd = shift;
    my($zipin_fh, $zipout_fh,@base64);
    ::open3($zipin_fh,$zipout_fh,">&STDERR","bzip2 -9");
    if(fork) {
    close $zipin_fh;
    @base64 = <$zipout_fh>;
    close $zipout_fh;
    } else {
    close $zipout_fh;
    print $zipin_fh @_;
    close $zipin_fh;
    exit;
    }
    ::debug("zip","Orig:@_\nAs bzip2:@base64\n");
    return @base64;
}

sub undef_if_empty {
    if(defined($_[0]) and $_[0] eq "") {
    return undef;
    }
    return $_[0];
}

sub debug {
    # Uses:
    #   $Global::debug
    #   %Global::fd
    # Returns: N/A
    print @_[1..$#_];
}

package SQL;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $dburl = shift;
    $Global::use{"DBI"} ||= eval "use DBI; 1;";
    my %options = parse_dburl($dburl);
    my %driveralias = ("sqlite" => "SQLite",
               "sqlite3" => "SQLite",
               "pg" => "Pg",
               "postgres" => "Pg",
               "postgresql" => "Pg");
    my $driver = $driveralias{$options{'databasedriver'}} || $options{'databasedriver'};
    my $database = $options{'database'};
    my $host = $options{'host'} ? ";host=".$options{'host'} : "";
    my $port = $options{'port'} ? ";port=".$options{'port'} : "";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database$host$port";
    my $userid = $options{'user'};
    my $password = $options{'password'};;
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1 })
    or die $DBI::errstr;
    return bless {
    'dbh' => $dbh,
    'max_number_of_args' => undef,
    'table' => $options{'table'},
    }, ref($class) || $class;
}

sub parse_dburl {
    my $url = shift;
    my %options = ();
    # sql:mysql://[[user][:password]@][host][:port]/[database[/table][?sql query]]

    if($url=~m!(?:sql:)? # You can prefix with 'sql:'
               ((?:oracle|ora|mysql|pg|postgres|postgresql)(?:s|ssl|)|
                 (?:sqlite|sqlite2|sqlite3)):// # Databasedriver ($1)
               (?:
                ([^:@/][^:@]*|) # Username ($2)
                (?:
                 :([^@]*) # Password ($3)
                )?
               @)?
               ([^:/]*)? # Hostname ($4)
               (?:
                :
                ([^/]*)? # Port ($5)
               )?
               (?:
                /
                ([^/?]*)? # Database ($6)
               )?
               (?:
                /
                ([^?]*)? # Table ($7)
               )?
               (?:
                \?
                (.*)? # Query ($8)
               )?
              !ix) {
    $options{databasedriver} = ::undef_if_empty(lc(uri_unescape($1)));
    $options{user} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($2));
    $options{password} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($3));
    $options{host} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($4));
    $options{port} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($5));
    $options{database} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($6));
    $options{table} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($7));
    $options{query} = ::undef_if_empty(uri_unescape($8));
    ::debug("sql","dburl $url\n");
    ::debug("sql","databasedriver ",$options{databasedriver}, " user ", $options{user},
          " password ", $options{password}, " host ", $options{host},
          " port ", $options{port}, " database ", $options{database},
          " table ",$options{table}," query ",$options{query}, "\n");

    } else {
    ::error("$url is not a valid DBURL");
    exit 255;
    }
    return %options;
}

sub uri_unescape {
    # Copied from http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/URI-1.55/URI/Escape.pm
    # to avoid depending on URI::Escape
    # This section is (C) Gisle Aas.
    # Note from RFC1630:  "Sequences which start with a percent sign
    # but are not followed by two hexadecimal characters are reserved
    # for future extension"
    my $str = shift;
    if (@_ && wantarray) {
    # not executed for the common case of a single argument
    my @str = ($str, @_);  # need to copy
    foreach (@str) {
        s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
    }
    return @str;
    }
    $str =~ s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg if defined $str;
    $str;
}

sub run {
    my $self = shift;
    my $stmt = shift;
    my $dbh = $self->{'dbh'};
    ::debug("sql","run $stmt\n");
    # Execute with the rest of the args - if any
    my $rv;
    my $sth;
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
    $rv = $sth->execute(@_);
    return $sth;
}

sub table {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->{'table'};
}

sub create_table {
    my $self = shift;
    my $table = $self->table();
    $self->run(qq(DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table;));
    $self->run(qq{CREATE TABLE $table
        (Seq INT,
         Exitval INT
         }.
           qq{);});
}

sub insert_records {
    my $self = shift;
    my $seq = shift;
    my $record_ref = shift;
    my $table = $self->table();
    $self->run("INSERT INTO $table (Seq,Exitval) ".
           "VALUES (?,?);", $seq, -1000);
}
```

Comment: Try to reduce the problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @glennjackman It is basically what it is. I only included the library functions directly, so you would not have to install special libraries to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the child or parent process exits, it closes its database handle and associated socket, and on the server side, the corresponding backend quits.

From that point onward, if the other (still-existing) client process tries to use the database handle, sending queries will fail with *MySQL server has gone away* or with postgres *server closed the connection unexpectedly*. These messages seem to quite correctly describe what happened.

The primary workaround is to call `DBI->connect()` after `fork` and not share the db handle between processes in any way.

If the database activity is confined to the parent, you may set `AutoInactiveDestroy` early on the db handle (since DBI 1.614). This should set `InactiveDestroy` automatically in the childs and just solve the problem. See `InactiveDestroy` in DBI documentation:

> For a database handle, this attribute does not disable an explicit
>   call to the disconnect method, only the implicit call from DESTROY
>   that happens if the handle is still marked as Active.
>
> This attribute is specifically designed for use in Unix applications
>   that "fork" child processes. For some drivers, when the child process
>   exits the destruction of inherited handles cause the corresponding
>   handles in the parent process to cease working.
>
> Either the parent or the child process, but not both, should set
>   InactiveDestroy true on all their shared handles. Alternatively, and
>   preferably, the "AutoInactiveDestroy" can be set in the parent on
>   connect.

Comment: Great analysis which seems to hold. Problem is that in the real code forks (like the above) are being done all over the place. Is there a way to tell the forked process, that the DBI-handle is the parent's and should not be touched?

Comment: @Ole: `[Auto]InactiveDestroy` should do, see edit